# commutative monoids have binary products?

Tags: semigroups-and-monoids

Does the category CMonoid of commutative monoids have binary products?

thanks

Comment: My immediate response is: yes; take, the Cartesian product.  Am I missing some subtlety here?

Comment: Closed. Reason: Wikipedia.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, and in fact all products exist: take the usual Cartesian product, with coordinatewise monoid operation.